# Statefulset Pods : Issue with Multiple Persistent Volume Claims

Tags: kubernetes

Since I have 5 shared NFS folders:

```
   root@k8s-eu-1-master:~# df -h | grep /srv/
   aa.aaa.aaa.aaa:/srv/shared-k8s-eu-1-worker-1 391G 6.1G 365G 2% /mnt/data
   bb.bbb.bbb.bbb:/srv/shared-k8s-eu-1-worker-2 391G 6.1G 365G 2% /mnt/data
   cc.ccc.ccc.cc:/srv/shared-k8s-eu-1-worker-3 391G 6.1G 365G 2% /mnt/data
   dd.ddd.ddd.dd:/srv/shared-k8s-eu-1-worker-4 391G 6.1G 365G 2% /mnt/data
   ee.eee.eee.eee:/srv/shared-k8s-eu-1-worker-5 391G 6.1G 365G 2% /mnt/data
```

I added in cassandra-statefulset.yaml the second volumeMount with its volumeClaimTemplate:

```
  # These volume mounts are persistent. They are like inline claims,
  # but not exactly because the names need to match exactly one of
  # the stateful pod volumes.
  volumeMounts:
  - name: k8s-eu-1-worker-1
   mountPath: /srv/shared-k8s-eu-1-worker-1
  - name: k8s-eu-1-worker-2
   mountPath: /srv/shared-k8s-eu-1-worker-2

   # These are converted to volume claims by the controller
   # and mounted at the paths mentioned above.
   # do not use these in production until ssd GCEPersistentDisk or other ssd pd
   volumeClaimTemplates:
   - metadata:
     name: k8s-eu-1-worker-1
    spec:
     accessModes: [ "ReadWriteOnce" ]
     storageClassName: k8s-eu-1-worker-1
     resources:
      requests:
       storage: 1Gi
   - metadata:
     name: k8s-eu-1-worker-2
    spec:
     accessModes: [ "ReadWriteOnce" ]
     storageClassName: k8s-eu-1-worker-2
     resources:
       requests:
       storage: 1Gi

  ---
  kind: StorageClass
  apiVersion: storage.k8s.io/v1
  metadata:
   name: k8s-eu-1-worker-1
  provisioner: k8s-sigs.io/k8s-eu-1-worker-1
  parameters:
   type: pd-ssd

  kind: StorageClass
  apiVersion: storage.k8s.io/v1
  metadata:
   name: k8s-eu-1-worker-2
  provisioner: k8s-sigs.io/k8s-eu-1-worker-2
  parameters:
   type: pd-ssd
```

It seems working fine at the beginning:

```
   root@k8s-eu-1-master:~# kubectl apply -f ./cassandraStatefulApp/cassandra-statefulset.yaml 
   statefulset.apps/cassandra created
```

But the statefulset remains in a "not-ready" state:

```
   root@k8s-eu-1-master:~# kubectl get sts
   NAME    READY AGE
   cassandra 0/3  17m

root@k8s-eu-1-master:~# kubectl describe sts cassandra
  Name:       cassandra
  Namespace:     default
  CreationTimestamp: Wed, 08 Nov 2023 12:02:10 +0100
  Selector:     app=cassandra
  Labels:      app=cassandra
  Annotations:    <none>
  Replicas:     3 desired | 1 total
  Update Strategy:  RollingUpdate
   Partition:    0
  Pods Status:    0 Running / 1 Waiting / 0 Succeeded / 0 Failed
  Pod Template:
   Labels: app=cassandra
   Containers:
    cassandra:
    Image:   gcr.io/google-samples/cassandra:v13
    Ports:   7000/TCP, 7001/TCP, 7199/TCP, 9042/TCP
    Host Ports: 0/TCP, 0/TCP, 0/TCP, 0/TCP
    Limits:
     cpu:  500m
     memory: 1Gi
    Requests:
     cpu:   500m
     memory: 1Gi
    Readiness: exec [/bin/bash -c /ready-probe.sh] delay=15s timeout=5s period=10s #success=1  
#failure=3
    Environment:
     MAX_HEAP_SIZE:     512M
     HEAP_NEWSIZE:      100M
     CASSANDRA_SEEDS:    cassandra-0.cassandra.default.svc.cluster.local
     CASSANDRA_CLUSTER_NAME: K8Demo
     CASSANDRA_DC:      DC1-K8Demo
     CASSANDRA_RACK:     Rack1-K8Demo
     POD_IP:         (v1:status.podIP)
    Mounts:
     /srv/shared-k8s-eu-1-worker-1 from k8s-eu-1-worker-1 (rw)
     /srv/shared-k8s-eu-1-worker-2 from k8s-eu-1-worker-2 (rw)
   Volumes: <none>
  Volume Claims:
   Name:     k8s-eu-1-worker-1
   StorageClass: k8s-eu-1-worker-1
   Labels:    <none>
   Annotations: <none>
   Capacity:   1Gi
   Access Modes: [ReadWriteOnce]
   Name:     k8s-eu-1-worker-2
   StorageClass: k8s-eu-1-worker-2
   Labels:    <none>
   Annotations: <none>
   Capacity:   1Gi
   Access Modes: [ReadWriteOnce]
  Events:
   Type  Reason      Age From          Message
   ----  ------      ---- ----          -------
   Normal SuccessfulCreate 18m statefulset-controller create Claim k8s-eu-1-worker-1-cassandra-0   
    Pod cassandra-0 in StatefulSet cassandra success
   Normal SuccessfulCreate 18m statefulset-controller create Claim k8s-eu-1-worker-2-cassandra-0 
    Pod cassandra-0 in StatefulSet cassandra success
   Normal SuccessfulCreate 18m statefulset-controller create Pod cassandra-0 in StatefulSet 
 cassandra successful
```

The corresponding pod remains in "Pending" State :

```
   root@k8s-eu-1-master:~# kubectl get pods
   NAME                               READY STATUS  RESTARTS AGE
   cassandra-0                           0/1  Pending 0     19m
   k8s-eu-1-worker-1-nfs-subdir-external-provisioner-79fff4ff2qx7k 1/1  Running 0     19h

  root@k8s-eu-1-master:~# kubetl describe pod cassandra-0
  kubetl: command not found
  root@k8s-eu-1-master:~# kubectl describe pod cassandra-0
  Name:      cassandra-0
  Namespace:    default
  Priority:    0
  Service Account: default
  Node:      <none>
  Labels:     app=cassandra
           apps.kubernetes.io/pod-index=0
           controller-revision-hash=cassandra-79d64cd8b
           statefulset.kubernetes.io/pod-name=cassandra-0
  Annotations:   <none>
  Status:     Pending
  IP:       
  IPs:       <none>
  Controlled By:  StatefulSet/cassandra
  Containers:
   cassandra:
    Image:   gcr.io/google-samples/cassandra:v13
    Ports:   7000/TCP, 7001/TCP, 7199/TCP, 9042/TCP
    Host Ports: 0/TCP, 0/TCP, 0/TCP, 0/TCP
    Limits:
     cpu:  500m
     memory: 1Gi
    Requests:
     cpu:   500m
     memory: 1Gi
    Readiness: exec [/bin/bash -c /ready-probe.sh] delay=15s timeout=5s period=10s #success=1  
#failure=3
    Environment:
     MAX_HEAP_SIZE:     512M
     HEAP_NEWSIZE:      100M
     CASSANDRA_SEEDS:    cassandra-0.cassandra.default.svc.cluster.local
     CASSANDRA_CLUSTER_NAME: K8Demo
     CASSANDRA_DC:      DC1-K8Demo
     CASSANDRA_RACK:     Rack1-K8Demo
     POD_IP:         (v1:status.podIP)
    Mounts:
     /srv/shared-k8s-eu-1-worker-1 from k8s-eu-1-worker-1 (rw)
     /srv/shared-k8s-eu-1-worker-2 from k8s-eu-1-worker-2 (rw)
     /var/run/secrets/kubernetes.io/serviceaccount from kube-api-access-wxx58 (ro)
  Conditions:
   Type     Status
   PodScheduled False 
  Volumes:
   k8s-eu-1-worker-1:
    Type:   PersistentVolumeClaim (a reference to a PersistentVolumeClaim in the same namespace)
    ClaimName: k8s-eu-1-worker-1-cassandra-0
    ReadOnly: false
   k8s-eu-1-worker-2:
    Type:   PersistentVolumeClaim (a reference to a PersistentVolumeClaim in the same namespace)
    ClaimName: k8s-eu-1-worker-2-cassandra-0
    ReadOnly: false
   kube-api-access-wxx58:
    Type:          Projected (a volume that contains injected data from multiple sources)
    TokenExpirationSeconds: 3607
    ConfigMapName:     kube-root-ca.crt
    ConfigMapOptional:   <nil>
    DownwardAPI:      true
  QoS Class:         Guaranteed
  Node-Selectors:       <none>
  Tolerations:        node.kubernetes.io/not-ready:NoExecute op=Exists for 300s
                 node.kubernetes.io/unreachable:NoExecute op=Exists for 300s
  Events:
   Type  Reason      Age        From       Message
   ----  ------      ----       ----       -------
   Warning FailedScheduling 20m        default-scheduler 0/6 nodes are available: pod has unbound 
immediate PersistentVolumeClaims. preemption: 0/6 nodes are available: 6 Preemption is not helpful  
for scheduling..
   Warning FailedScheduling 10m (x3 over 20m) default-scheduler 0/6 nodes are available: pod has 
unbound immediate PersistentVolumeClaims. preemption: 0/6 nodes are available: 6 Preemption is not 
helpful for scheduling..
```

With only one of the two Persistent Volume Claims in "Bound" Status, and the other one still "Pending" Status:

```
  root@k8s-eu-1-master:~# kubectl get pvc
  NAME              STATUS  VOLUME                  CAPACITY ACCESS MODES STORAGECLASS    
AGE
  k8s-eu-1-worker-1-cassandra-0 Bound  pvc-4f1d877b-8e01-4b76-b4e1-25bc226fd1a5 1Gi    RWO         
  k8s-eu-1-worker-1 21m
  k8s-eu-1-worker-2-cassandra-0 Pending                                    k8s-eu-1-worker-2 21m
```

What's wrong with my `cassandra-statefulset.yaml` setting above?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My fault

I didn't create the second `k8s-eu-1-worker-2-nfs-subdir-external-provisioner`

Once I created it, the stateful pod went in Running State

Comment: Please accept answers to your question when they are solve (by clicking on the tickmark on the left of the question). Otherwise, the questions will stay in the system as unsolved forever. You will even get a little reputation for accepting the answers.